# Cálculo do rotacional divergente de uma função no Matlab

Tags: matlab

Estou com um trabalho da faculdade onde devo criar uma rotina para calcular o rotacional divergente de uma função qualquer no matlab.

Pesquisando, encontrei que posso usar a função `divergence()` para calcular o divergente dos vetores imputados pelo usuário.

Iniciei o código:

```
clc 
clear

%Calcular o divergente da função

i = input('Insira o vetor i: ');
j = input('Insira o vetor j: ');
k = input('Insira o vetor k: ');

div = divergence(i,i,k);
printf(div);
```

Quando insiro alguma letra na pergunta, ele retorna o erro abaixo (coloquei "2x"):

> "Error using input
>   Undefined function or variable 'x'."

Quando insiro apenas números, consigo chegar até a parte de calcular o divergente, mas dá esse erro:

> "Error using divergence (line 54)
>   U,V,W must all be a 3D arrays."

Gostaria muito da ajuda de vocês, se possível!

Apenas lembrando que o divergente é calculado pela derivada parcial de i em relação a x, j em relação a y e k em relação a z.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você tem duas opcões aqui.

Para estar utilizando `2*x` é necessário a [funcão simbólica](https://se.mathworks.com/products/symbolic.html) do MATLAB.

Caso este seja o caso, vc pode usar este exemplo direto to help:

```
syms x y z; divergence([x^2 2*y z], [x y z])
```

Caso você queira usar a mesma funcão mas com o modo numérico, a definicão é um pouco mais complexa e exige matrizes 3D (motivo do erro), geradas com o uso do `meshgrid` ou com sua funcão pra definir o espaco 3D.